# Chrome extension: is there a ways to access the $0 (the selected console element) from an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access the $0 (which is the last selected element in the chrome developers tools) for an extension I'm building.

Any way to do so?

**More information:**
The extension is a page action extension. It has several features and I want to have an option to inquire about the current selected object ($0).

Can I keep it as a page extension extension or dof I have to go developer tool plugin way?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what your extension does? I assume from what you are asking that you are building a dev tools plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$0` is only meaningful when the developer tools are still activated. The only way to get the result of `$0` is through a [devtools page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html).

A devtools page can communicate with the rest of your extension using the [message passing APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). Under normal circumstances, the state of the dev tools (open/closed) is known and fixed for the lifetime of the (page action) popup <sup>the devtools cannot be toggled while the popup is open *unless* the popup is [being inspected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup)</sup>.
So, the devtools page should be a receiver <sup>[`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage) or [`chrome.runtime.onConnect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onConnect)</sup>, and the popup should be a sender <sup>[`chrome.riuntime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/riuntime.html#method-sendMessage) or [`chrome.runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-connect)</sup>.

Within the dev tools page, you can easily interact with the last inspected element using [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-eval):

```
// E.g. Test if the currently inspected element is the main <body> element
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('$0 === document.body', function(result) {
    alert('$0 is ' + (result ? '' : 'not ') + '<body>');
});
```

The result of the last expression is passed back to the callback. This value must be serializable, so you cannot "return" the DOM element itself. Consequently, you cannot get direct access to the DOM element, any interaction with the inspected element has to be done through the devtools API.

Comment: LOL @Rob - it makes me lazy to know you will always come up with a great answer when a chrome extension is involved. My 2 cents: Actually I believe there **is** a way to pass the element itself, by executing a function in the JS context of the content script (of course you need to have a context script injected into the page under inspection). **[The docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html#selected-element)** have a handy example.

Comment: @ExpertSystem That's indeed a handy way to get hold of a reference to the inspected element in a content script. However, that still does not offer direct access to the DOM element in the page action popup.

Comment: Yeah, I meant "pass the element itself _to a content script_" (not to the page-action popup.