# In Chrome DevTools extension, how to retrieve selected node from multi-frame page for extension elements sidebar pane

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I'm developing a Chrome devtools extension that displays content in an elements sidebar pane based on the currently selected node. As described in the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow), the mechanism for working with the selected node is calling `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval`, with the eval'd code including `$0`, the variable pointing to the most recently selected node. For example, to display the currently selected node in the console, I could call `eval('console.log($0)')`. For background on this issue, see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400796/chrome-extension-is-there-a-ways-to-access-the-0-the-selected-console-element).

The problem I have concerns pages containing iframes. The eval call takes an options object with a frameURL property. For example:

`eval('console.log($0)',{frameURL: 'http://www.iframeexample.com'})`.

This allows the caller to evaluate the code in a specific frame. However, each frame (except `about:blank` srcs) has its own `$0` variable pointing to the most recently selected node in that frame's window. If a page has five frames, there are five different values for `$0`, one for each frame. When my extension receives the [onSelectionChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ElementsPanel) event, how can I know which node the user has currently selected in the devtools elements panel, i.e. which frame's window $0 points to correct node? How can I possibly provide content for the correct node?

My second related [problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=841429) involves iframes with similar sources. For example, the page [frames.com](http://www.frames.com) has two iframe elements with the same `src` (excluding differences in the `src` hash value). A call to eval with the duplicate src value will execute in one of the frames, but not the other. I can find no way to check both frames for the currently selected node, `$0`. In this case, if the user selects a node in the frame that I cannot access via an eval call, there is no way to serve content related to that node.

Providing content or functionality related to the currently selected node is the key use case for adding a devtools extension element sidebar panel. The [onSelectionChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ElementsPanel) event fires when the extension should check for a new selection, but the event callback receives no information on the selected node.  Given the problems described above, it seems impossible to reliably locate the user's node selection on multi-frame pages. Am I missing something fundamental in my approach?

Comment: The API is just this bad. I think I've seen this already reported on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Any updates to this? Tried to search on crbug but couldn't find a related bug

Comment: @zewa666 Unfortunately I have no updates. My experience to date in finding and submitting bugs regarding the chrome extension environment is that they are not addressed. The only exception to this rule is an extension API call I found that caused the extension process to crash. That issue was quickly fixed.

Comment: @zewa666 The related bug is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=841429